# Making something not look clickable

Tags: website-design, buttons, user-expectation, tags

I haven't tested this theory, but I have a feeling users of my website may believe that the 'Concept' tag is clickable, when it isn't. How can I make it clear that this is not a button?

[image]

Comment: What is the larger context, and the purpose of this tag?

Comment: I've put up a quick suggestion based on the info you've provided. Will there be more than one tag displayed in this area, or just the 'concept' tag?

Answer (score 5):

We don't have the larger context of your problem, so here's some quick thoughts:

You could try making an element that looks more like a banner (or a bookmark). If you want to reduce the visual noise, you can make it a bit more subtle, so the other content stands out. You can use a lighter font so it's distinct from the actual content.

[image]

Here's a version w/ lighter and tucked completely into the corner, and one where you don't put any borders, just a simple gray text.

[image]

[image]

Comment: These are great options. I recommend number 1, as it is the most obvious, and does not looks like a button or a link.

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways that I think tags are typically different from buttons:

1. They have less padding
2. The colours and text aren't designed to stand out so much, i.e. washed out background colour and less contrast between background and foreground colours

**GMail:**

[image]

**UX.SE:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to think of the issue, that comes in two steps:

- what do people *think* should happen when they click on [Concept]?
- can you implement that?

If people click it, most likely they're hoping to sort of "zoom in", to somehow get *more details* about the tag content.  So maybe you can show a list of everything that's tagged with "Concept".  But if all you can do is show a little pop-up defining what a "Concept" is, that's still granting the user some extra detail.